# how can update DB using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

I am working on project which uses jsf 1.X and hibernate, where am new. We are using below code to update_

```
        Shift4DAO dao = Shift4DAO.getInstance();
        Session session = dao.createNewSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(shift4B);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (final HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
```

How *session.saveOrUpdate(shift4B);* it is working(Flow)?
where *Shift4DAO.java*

```
public class Shift4DAO extends BaseShift4DAO {

public Shift4DAO () {}
}
```

And *Shift4.java*

```
public class Shift4 extends BaseShift4 {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public Shift4 () {
    super();
}


public Shift4 (java.lang.Integer id) {
    super(id);
}


public Shift4 (
    java.lang.Integer id,
    org.azureworlds.dao.Employee createdBy,
    org.azureworlds.dao.Employee lastUpdatedBy,
    org.azureworlds.dao.Reservation reservation) {

    super (
        id,
        createdBy,
        lastUpdatedBy,
        reservation);
}

}
```

I fail to understand how i get connect to update for updating data.
is anybody can simplify this, where i need to check or how connecting to HB?
Thank u!!!!

Comment: the question is not really clear. You showed code which probably works and ask how to do it? what is the problem

Comment: i am studing this code , but i didnt understand how data flows into this code, and how it connects to other code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dao.createNewSession();` creates a hibernate session which encapsulates a database connection and implements the "Unit of Work" pattern. `session.saveOrUpdate(shift4B);` tells the session that `shift4B` should be created(INSERT) or updated depending on the state of the entity (new or changed).

Comment: but how he finds its corresponding javaBean class and go to HBconfi?

Comment: in the hbm mapping there is the class specified which the mapping belongs to. Hibernate uses shift4B.class.Fullname to get the corresponding mapping and all it needs is defined there

Comment: tnx, and why we used DAO which is nothing,just have blank constructor? 
means when i do saveOrUpdate(obj) then it go for _obj_'s class through HBM file?